# Homotopy colimit description of stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-algebraic-geometry, descent, simplicial-presheaves

Let $F$ be an Artin stack. If $p: X \to F$ is an atlas for $F$, can we express $F$, in the $\infty$-category ${\rm Shv}^{\acute{et}}(k)$ of  higher stacks, as a homotopy colimit over the simplicial diagram 
$$
... \rightrightarrows X \times_{F} X \rightrightarrows X
$$
in ${\rm Shv} ^{\acute{et}}(k)$? I ask this because we know that if $U_{\bullet} \to X$ is a hypercover, for a scheme $X$, this fact is built into the very definition of ${\rm Shv} ^{\acute{et}}(k)$. Indeed, by Dugger, Hollander, Isaksen, (in the language of model categories) one obtains ${\rm Shv} ^{\acute{et}}(k)$ as a Bousfield localization of $s{\rm Pre}(k)$ (the category of simplicial presheaves) by inverting morphisms 
$$
hocolim_{\Delta} U_{\bullet} \to X
$$

So I'm wondering if we can deduce this fact about a more general higher sheaf or stack $F$ from the scheme case.

Comment: What is your definition of atlas? If it is simply a representable smooth surjective morphism, then your question should follow easily from the fact that being an effective epimorphism is a local notion (proposition 6.2.3.15 in Higher Topos Theory)